# Mantener la sesión de un skill Alexa abierta, para lanzar otro intent

Tags: aws, alexa

Quiero saber si se puede mantener UN skill abierto de Alexa, comento mi caso:

Estoy creando un skill con 3 intents, al ejecutar cada uno Alexa te dará un mensaje estatico (sin interacción de vuelta de parte del usuario).
Si yo llamo al skill "open..." y luego activo cualquier intent (con su utterance) funciona, pero si quiero ejecutar el otro intent tengo que volver a decir lo de "open...".

Entiendo que la sesión se me está cerrando al finalizar el Intent.

¿Cómo puedo mantener abierta la sesión para que se puedan consultar varios Intents a medida que los activas por voz sin necesidad de invocarlo otra vez "open..."?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return handlerInput.responseBuilder
        .speak(outputSpeech)
        .reprompt('Mensaje en caso de que el usuario se quede callado')
        .getResponse();
```

Con esto podras mantener activa la skill y ejecutar otro intent despues de haber ejecutado uno previamente. En caso de que el usuario se quede callado le devolvera un mensaje "Mensaje en caso de que el usuario se quede callado".